# Rabbitmq not connecting from Paho js client

Tags: rabbitmq, mqtt, paho

Here is my paho javascript client code

```
  client = new Paho.MQTT.Client(host, Number(port), clientId);

  client.onMessageArrived = onMessageArrived;
  client.onMessageDelivered = onMessageDelivered;
  client.onConnectionLost = onConnectionLost;
```

here `port` `8083` works with other broker but not with Rabbitmq. In the documentation I could not found any correct port number.

Running `sudo rabbitmqctl status` gives

```
  [{rabbitmq_management,"RabbitMQ Management Console","3.6.2"},
      {rabbitmq_web_dispatch,"RabbitMQ Web Dispatcher","3.6.2"},
      {webmachine,"webmachine","1.10.3"},
      {mochiweb,"MochiMedia Web Server","2.13.1"},
      {rabbitmq_mqtt,"RabbitMQ MQTT Adapter","3.6.2"},
 {listeners,[{clustering,25672,"::"},{amqp,5672,"::"},{mqtt,1883,"::"}]},
```

So I tried with port `1883` also. I was following https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-web-mqtt-examples/blob/master/priv/echo.html

I getting this error:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:1883/mqtt' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response

Comment: Have you installed the mqtt-web plugin (https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-web-mqtt)? MQTT over websockets is not going to be on the same port as pure MQTT

Comment: no i havnt installed this but as I i have mentioned `{rabbitmq_mqtt,"RabbitMQ MQTT Adapter","3.6.2"}` is shown by rabbitmq

Comment: Which will get you pure MQTT not MQTT over websockets

Comment: yes installing that plugin worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As thrashed out in the comments:

Rabbitmq requires the following plugin to support MQTT over websockets (http://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-web-mqtt)